# Bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: set-theory

Importantly, I am looking for a constructive proof (which does not rely on the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem). Motivated by [this discussion](http://www.quora.com/Mathematics/What-would-be-an-elegant-proof-for-the-assertion-that-mathbb-R-is-numerically-equivalent-to-mathbb-R-2).

Comment: Here is something which might not work exactly, but should be on the right lines: represent pairs of real numbers as pairs of binary strings, then interleave them. (My caveat is because of non-uniqueness issues to do with $\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} = 2^0$ but one should be able to tweak the idea.)

Comment: @Mark, if you want to suggest using a transcendence basis, how would that be constructive? It relies on the axiom of choice.  

Comment: @Mark: If one sticks to the original theorem, and assumes injections then no use of choice is needed. If one wants to get clever and use surjections instead, then the axiom of choice is needed.

Comment: I assume by constructive, you mean just mean "without Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder and without axiom of choice" (the former is actually provable without the later).  But if you happen to mean constructive in the style of, say, Bishop's constructive math, then you need a homoemorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$, of which none exists (or at least I recall having heard this, I don't know the proof off hand that there is none).  This gives some insight into why this is a tricky problem.

Comment: @Jason, why does a Bishop-constructive bijection have to be a homeomorphism? (As for why the two are not homeomorphic in their usual topologies, removing a point from R disconnects it, but removing a point from R^2 does not.)

Comment: @Yemon, let me back track a little.  In constructive math, everything is in a sense computable and relates back to the natural numbers.  From Bishop's book _Foundations of constructive analysis_ (p 63): "A function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a rule which associates an element $b=f(a)$ of a set $B$ to each element $a$ of a set $A$, _in such a way that $b$ can be found by a finite routine when $a$ is given_."  I believe what he is saying is that (a code for) $b$ is computable from (a code for) $a$, and the standard constructive codings of reals lead to such functions being continuous. .../...

Comment: @Yemon, .../... Now I suppose that one could use a different notion of function, for example a Borel map. Indeed constructive mathematics can easily talk about Borel maps since they are easily codable. I think your proof above for example would constructively show there is a Borel bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Anyway, the point is that there aren't nice continuous bijections so there isn't a nice formula that describes a bijection.  Instead you need to do a lot of cutting and pasting to get the bijection.  (p.s.  I am not an expert on constructive math.)

Comment: Right, both Etienne and Goldstern solutions make non-trivial use of the law of excluded middle, which is not allowed in constructive mathematics. The existence of a discontinuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ is basically equivalent to the law of excluded middle for arithmetical statements.

Comment: Asaf, many constructive systems include the axiom of choice or large fragments thereof, so using the axiom of choice is not a very good test for non-constructiveness.

Comment: @jason: Constructive math can talk about Borel codes for maps, but you cannot apply these maps to specific (constructively given) reals. @piyush: please clarify what you mean by "constructive". Bishop?

Comment: Goldstern, I think the OP meant explicit rather than constructive. By that standard, your answer is correct (and actually very good!).

Comment: Bishop on choice and constructive math: "When a classical mathematician claims he is a constructivist, he probably means he avoids the axiom of choice.  This axiom is unique in its ability to trouble the conscience of the classical mathematician, but in fact it is not a real source of the unconstructivities of classical mathematics. A choice function exists in constructive mathematics, because a choice is implied by the very meaning of existence. ... **The axiom of choice is used to extract elements from equivalence classes when they should have never been put there in the first place.**"

Comment: If OP meant explicit rather than constructive, then Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein ought to be acceptable, since applications thereof can be made perfectly explicit. Of course, the question as stated is pretty vague on such matters (surely excluded middle is unavoidable?). 

Comment: The Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem yields a constructive proof and **does not** rely on the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem.

Comment: In mathematical logic, we often see the word "reals" used to mean the space $\omega^\omega$ of sequences of natural numbers.  In that case, your map is easy.  Who knows why logicians do that?  In any case, your question reduces to: Find a constructive bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\omega^\omega$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar or between $\mathbf{R}$ and $k^\omega$ for any $2\le k\le\omega$ for your favorite choice of $k$.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a bijection that uses the decimal (or binary, whatever) expansion of reals. (Even though I think the approach using continued fractions is more canonical.)

- Let $\alpha:\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ and $\beta:[0,1)\times [0,1)\to [0,1)$ be bijections.
- Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb Z \times [0,1) $ be the natural bijection $x\mapsto (\lfloor x\rfloor, x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$.
- Together, $f$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ will define bijections $$ \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \to^f (\mathbb Z\times [0,1)) \times (\mathbb Z\times [0,1)) \simeq \mathbb Z^2 \times [0,1)^2 \to ^{\alpha,\beta} \mathbb Z \times [0,1) \to^{f^{-1}}\mathbb R$$

The main part is of course the definition of $\beta$.  [EDIT: This is not my construction; I am not sure where I first read it.  In his book on the real numbers, Oliver Deiser gives a very similar construction (blocking zeroes instead of nines) and calls this Julius König's trick.  [König's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyula_K%C5%91nig) mentions it but omits the details.]

Represent each real number $x\in [0,1)$
as a sequence of DIGITS, where each DIGIT is either in $\{0,\ldots,8\}$ or is of the form $10*(10^k-1)+i$ with $k\ge 1$ and $i\in \{0,\ldots,8\}$ (i.e., in $\{90,\ldots, 98; 990,\ldots, 998; 9990,\ldots, 9998; \ldots\}$.

For example, the number 0.0129449956$\dots$ would be represented by $(0,1,2,94,4,995,6,\ldots)$.

Given a pair $(x,y)$, $\beta$ interleaves these two representations.

Comment: But is the greatest integer function constructive? After all, one may not constructively decide if a real number is equal to $5$ or slightly less.

Comment: Probably not, depending on what you exactly is meant by "constructive".  (As discussed above - if every constructive function is continuous, then there is no bijection.)  Also depending on what you mean by "real number" - in my answer I implicitly define a real number to be a decimal representation without an infinite string of 9's.  In this context (which is NOT the definition I usually use for real numbers), my answer is constructive.  (Well, it needs some tweaking: For negative numbers I really should use $\lceil\cdot\rceil$.) 

Comment: "user2145334" leaves the following comment: "This proof is wrong, because there is no inverse image of 0.8689898989.. as (0.88888.., 0.69999..) is not allowed representation." Unfortunately their objection is not correct: the inverse image of 0.8689898989.. is the pair (0.88989898.. , 0.6989898..)

Comment: @DanPetersen Thanks editing, moving this text into a comment.  I agree that the objection was not correct.  I would have written "however" instead of "unfortunately", but I will not quarrel about this ...