# Continuous nowhere differentiability and constructive mathematics

Tags: constructive-mathematics, fractals

In some constructive systems, [every function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176285/24563) (roughly speaking from the classical fact that computable functions are continuous).  More weakly, in Bishop's constructive approach [one cannot prove](https://mathoverflow.net/q/164694/36972) the existence of discontinuous functions.

I am wondering: in such a system, is the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)
$$W_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \cos(b^n\pi x),\quad ab>1+3\pi/2$$
nowhere differentiable?  (It is well-known classically to be continuous but nowhere differentiable.)  Perhaps a broader, hence more interesting, question is whether one can construct a continuous but nowhere differentiable function in Bishop's mathematics.

Comment: I'm sure it's a naïve question, but, if $W_\alpha$ were constructively differentiable at a point, then wouldn't that imply that it was classically differentiable at that point?  I thought the point about all functions being continuous wasn't that discontinuous functions became continuous, but rather that one simply couldn't construct a discontinuous function in the first place.  (And, if that understanding is correct, does it automatically make sense to speak of the Weierstrass function?)

Comment: I don't really see what's non-constructive about the proof that the Weierstrass function is nowhere differentiable. You get a very explicit procedure for finding points that witness the failure of differentiability. Moreover, the function is computable, so Bishop can construct it.

Comment: The minor difficulty here is not with proving non-differentiability, but with proving continuity — because Bishop defines that as uniform continuity on compact intervals, and a classical proof might only show the pointwise continuity immediately. But the uniform continuity is provable too, and for a specific example like $a=\frac56$, $b=7$, it will be easy enough to write down an modulus of continuity explicitly.

Comment: @MattF. Bishop's definitions are usually understood as being defective. The statement that "The composition of two Bishop-continuous functions is Bishop-continuous" is equivalent to the "Fan Theorem" (awful name for what that is), but the Bishop school is consistent with the existence of Kleene Trees, which proves the negation of the Fan Theorem.

Comment: Your choices in the Bishop school are one of three: 1. Do point-free topology 2. accept the Fan Theorem 3. or use the *standard meaning* of the word continuous and treat it as something different from locally uniformly continuous. What you're suggesting is an overly literal reading of Bishop IMO.

Comment: @wlad, it is easy to prove a la Bishop that the composition of continuous functions is continuous, eg: If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ with $$|x-y|<q(\epsilon)\to |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$ and similarly $g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with $$|x-y|<r(\epsilon)\to |g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$$ then $x\to g(f(x))$ is uniformly continuous with $$|x-y|<r(q(\epsilon))\to |g(f(x))-g(f(y))|<\epsilon$$ with minimal modifications for other possible domains of $f$ and domain-dependent moduli for $g$.

Comment: @wlad, perhaps you mean that the fan theorem is equivalent to every pointwise continuous function being uniformly continuous. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00064.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual proofs are either constructive or can be made constructive fairly easily, sometimes by a slight weakening of the theorem. For example, let us read through [this note](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrent/files/104_weierstrass.pdf) by Brent Nelson. (Please read the four page proof before reading the rest of the answer.)

The first part, establishing that the Weierstraß function is uniformly continuous, is constructive.

The second part proves non-differentiability by demonstrating that the limit $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}$ does not exist. It is *not* an appeal proof by contradiction but a constructively valid [refutation by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#Refutation_by_contradiction).

There is just one sticky point, namely the proof tells us to select, for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, an integer $\alpha_m$ such that $$-1/2 < b^m x_0 - \alpha_m \leq 1/2.$$
These bounds are too tight, because constructively we cannot show that every real is within distance $1/2$ of an integer. (When $b^m x_0$ is very close to $1/2$ we have to be able to decide whether it is actually smaller than $1/2$ or not in order to determine whether $\alpha_m = 0$ or $\alpha_m = 1$.)

So let us relax the condition for $\alpha_m$ a bit and see if the rest of the proof goes through. Let $q > 0$ be a small "relaxation" rational (we shall impose additional conditions on it later as needed). Using countable choice, we can select integers $\alpha_m$ such that
$$-1/2 - q < b^m x_0 - \alpha_m < 1/2 + q.$$
This is possible because $q$ gives us a bit of wiggle room.
Now the proof proceeds by showing that two partial sums, called $S_1$ and $S_2$, are respectively very small and very large. Smallness of $S_1$ is unproblematic. The proof that $S_2$ is large depends on bounding $x_m = b^m x_0 - \alpha_m$ away from $1$ so that
$$
\frac{1 + \cos(b^n \pi x_m)}{1 + x_m}
$$
is seen to be positive. This is still the case with our $q$ thrown in as long as $q < 1/2$. But where the original proof gets the bound $2/3$ we obtain a slightly worse estimate
$$
\frac{1 + \cos(b^n \pi x_m)}{1 + x_m} \geq
\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2} + q} = \frac{2}{3 + q}.
$$
We can still salvage the rest of the proof by picking a small enough $q$: so long as $a b > 1 + (3 + q) \pi / 2$, the estimates in the rest of the proof will work. Since we assumed $a b > 1 + 3 \pi / 2$, there is a rational $q > 0$ such that $a b > 1 + (3 + q) \pi / 2$, so we use one such. (This was *not* an application of choice, because "choosing one thing known to exist" is formally an elimination of $\exists$.)

One would likely have to work a bit harder to also eliminate countable choice.

Comment: Can't the sequence $(\alpha_m)_m$ be computed from the sequence of digits of $x_0$ ? By looking at *e.g.* the convergents of $x_0$, each one being computed constructively using only a finite amount of digits.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier I think this could indeed work, at least assuming Markov's principle so that inequality becomes apartness. Prove the statement for when $x_0$ does *not* have a finite representation in base $b$, and prove it for when it *does* have a finite representation in base $b$. Since no real number $x$ can fail both conditions, the proof should go through.

Comment: When you say that we don't know whether every real is within distance $1$ of an integer, do you mean (as your inequality suggests) that we don't know whether every real is within distance $1/2$ of an integer (i.e., contained in an interval of diameter $1$ centered on an integer)?  Your argument (that we have to be careful for real numbers close to $1/2$) doesn't seem problematic if we are within distance $1$, since numbers close to $1/2$ are within distance $1$ of both $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier: how do you prove every real has a digit expansion? Also, even if you have one, how do you find $\alpha_m$ for the real whose digit expansion starts as $0.49999999\ldots$? You must pick $\alpha_m = 1$ if all digits are $9$, otherwise $\alpha_m = 0$, and that's not constructive (nor computable).

Comment: @LSpice: It cannot be shown constructively that $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (k, k+1]$, that's what the problem is. It may help to think how you would algorithmically determine from any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (given as a Cauchy sequence with a known rate of convergence) the $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $x \in (k, k+1]$. Answer: you can't do it.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1132407), are you sure the same the problem you are stating is the same as the one you have in mind? I think finding an integer within distance $1$ of a given real $x$ is finding an element $k \in \mathbb Z \cap (x - 1, x + 1)$, not finding an integer $k$ such that $x \in (k, k + 1]$. Can't I do the former by using a defining Cauchy sequence for $x$ to find a rational $r \in (x - 1/2, x + 1/2)$, and then finding an integer $k \in [r - 1/2, r + 1/2]$ (assuming $r$ is given explicitly as num/denom)?

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right, we need to find an integer within distance $1/2$. I mixed up the lengths of the intervals and distances to their endpoints. I'll fix the answer, thanks. Sorry, I was a bit too sloppy reading your comment at first.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: can't one define the reals as right-unlimited string of digits, in a stable form with unique writing (inspired from the non-adjacent form, say), so that  Cauchy sequences correspond to convergence of strings for the lexicographic order? I agree, though, that this differs from the definition of constructive reals, and I haven't put enough thought in this, but I thought it could be relevant.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier: Nope. You *can* use digit expansions if you allow negative and positive digits (say binary with digits $-1$, $0$, $1$) – but if you use the ordinary decimal expansion then things break. For instance, multiplication by 3 becomes non-computable.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: yes, that's what I meant by stable, clearly not the usual digits expansion.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier: I see, "stable" was a bit too cryptic for me. Still you cannot defne the functionw we are looking for, as it is discontinuous. Of course, it is not discontinuous if we change the domain from the reals to some other space, such as the one you are suggesting. But this move can be accomplished in general for any function – just make the domain more discrete.

Comment: This might deserve a separate question, but maybe an answer fits in a comment: why is the Weierstrass function not definable/defined in SDG (where every function is smooth)?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold: Because the object of smooth reals $R$ is not a complete metric space. You can't define reals there as limits of Cauchy sequences. The metric completion $\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is logically dense in $R$, by which I mean that $R \setminus \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh, I see, because a nilpotent is closer than any epsilon to 0, but we cannot conclude it's 0. Does that mean more generally, that the $\lim$-operation from "classical" calculus does not exist/is incompatible with SDG?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold: We need to be a bit careful, as SDG happens in intuitionistic logic (necessarily, the SDG axioms imply that excluded middle is false). How do we measure distance? It can't be $d : R \times R \to R$ because absolute value is not smooth. If we try to define limits of sequences topologically, using open intervals to generate topology, then the problem is that the topology so generated need not be $T_0$, as far as I can tell. Hmmm, I never actually thought about the true reason for completeness of $R$ not making sense.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I had mistaken impressions about constructive mathematics.  Just a point of detail: the proof that $S_2$ is large depends on bounding below a sum of terms, which are still non-negative in your variant, and bounding below the first term $n=0$, namely $\frac{1+\cos\pi x_m}{1+x_m} > \frac{1-\sin\pi q}{3/2+q}$, with a slightly worse numerator than you wrote.  This doesn't change the final conclusion, but the choice of $q$ is more annoying to state.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. I may fix the answer if I get a moment. (Or anyone else can, this site allows editing of other people's answers.)

Answer (score 2):

This is in the canonical source, Bishop and Bridges's 1985 *Constructive Analysis*.

See the exercises for chapter 2:

> 20. Construct a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'$
>     does not exist on any proper compact subinterval of $[0,1]$.

Comment: It seems like I've solved an exercise :-)

Comment: The way I understand Bishop's statement is that the set of non-differentiability points is dense.